# Nested whiles in C

Tags: c, loops

```
int count(int *a, int *b, int n) {
    int i=0,j=0,roz=0;

    while(i<n) {
        while(j<n) {
            if(a[i]==b[j])
                roz++;
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return roz;
}
```

n is the size of a, or b array (both are of the same size). The nested while loop seems to work only once, for i = 0. The next thing that seems to be happening is magically changing n into 1 (it is 5 at the beginning), so that the nested while doesn't loop the second time. Why is that so?

The interesting thing is that echoing n right before the return displays the right value, which is 5...

EDIT. For loops work properly here, but the question is still present.

Comment: Well, you could be invoking undefined behaviour if you read off the end of the arrays. That said, it's difficult to see how that could result in n being modified. How do you know that's the case?

Comment: So is this supposed to count the equal numbers in the two arrays, right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You never reset the value of `j` to 0.

Comment: Shit, good point here, thanks, didn't see this! :D

Comment: @khernik: this is exactly why you should be using the debugger to strip through your code line by line.

Comment: And why for loops are preferred to while loops in such situations. It is more difficult to forget to reset a counter using for-loop syntax.

Answer (score 3):

You should reset `j` to 0 between two nested loops.

```
while (i < n)
{
  j = 0;

  while (j < n)
  {
    if (a[i] == b[j])
      roz++;
  }
}
```

You could compute the intersection of two arrays in a more efficient way (there is a `O(N*log N)` solution).

Answer (score 1):

The value of `n` is not changed here. The reason nested loop is not executing for i = 1 or later is that you are not resetting the value of j. Say, `n` is 5. When i = 0 nested loop executes properly and the value of j is 5 after it finishes. When i = 1 then j is still 5 and so it never enters the nested loop.

```
while(i<n)
{
    j = 0; // reset j here to solve the problem
    while(j<n) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well by looking at the logic,it seems that you are conuting the number of common elements in both the arrays.

the mistake you are doing is you are not resetting the value of j to 0 in the first while loop.